# Is this differential form $\omega$ exact?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the differential form $\omega=yzdx+(y+xz+\frac{y-z}{y^2+z^2})dy+(xy+\frac{y+z}{y^2+z^2})dz$ and I want prove it's exact on the domain $\Omega=\{(x,y,z): y^2+z^2>0\}$

I have proved it's a closed form.If I found a regular curve $\gamma$ for which $\int_{\gamma} \omega \ne0$ the form isn't exact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, so what happens for $\gamma{: t}\to(0,\cos t,\sin t)$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$?